# Is it possible to make something appear below the bottom of a fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

What I want to do is make layout like this.

```
/****************************/
/                            /
/                            /
/                            /
/          Image             /
/                            /
/                            / /******************************/
/                            / /             Button           /
/****************************/ /******************************/
                               /*           TextView         */
```

The problem is, the button and Textview are supposed to be in a fragment of their own separate from the image. I want the button to align its bottom with that of the image in the parent activity while having objects in the same fragment that are below the image. How would I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your layout xml or how the fragments are handled in your `Activity` but the following solution should work.

Use the idea from the following code:

```
int imageFragmentHeight = mImageFragment.getView().getHeight();
// You might have to get the height some other way...
// e.g. using onGlobalLayoutListener

int buttonHeight = //Your button height

//Now position the button & ImageView fragment as required.

mButtonAndImageFragment.getView().setTranslationY((float)(imageFragmentHeight - buttonHeight));
```

My code assumes that both your `Fragments` have the same initial `top` position.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a little bit of logic. Just use the following steps:

1. Since you need the fragment containing the image side by side with the fragment containing the Button and TextView, use an horizontal LinearLayout and split the layout by setting android:layout_weight="1" to both fragments. This will split the layout equally between the 2 fragments (change the ratio to whatever you want).
2. The fragment containing the Image will have to have an ImageView and a View element (corresponding to the blank space). Use a LinearLayout as the root element. Set the height of this View (blank space) to be the height of the TextView. You should do this using weights. Say for example, you give the image a weight of 4 and give the view a weight of 1, they will split the available space in the ratio 4:1 (let's say that the total weight in this step is 5).
3. In the fragment containing the Image, use a LinearLayout as the root view. The first element will be a View (to correspond to the blank space), then a Button and then a TextView. Remember the total weight of the fragment in the previous step is 5 and the last element in the previous step had a weight of 1. So if you keep the weight of the LinearLayout as 5 in this step as well and keep the weight of the last TextView in this layout as 1, then you will find the button to have it's bottom aligned with the bottom of the Image in step 2.

> **NOTE:** The elements in step 3 will be split in the ration x:y:1 where
>   you should have x+y+1 = 5, x is the weight of the View and y is the
>   weight of the Button.
>
> **NOTE:** Keep in mind that weights are basically percentages of the
>   available space. Hence you do not strictly have to make sure that they
>   total to 5 (or any specific number) - I just mentioned them as an
>   example.